# Regex with grouping, how to terminate the group?

Tags: python, regex

I need to match the below with a regexp and want to accces the resulting group.

**String to be searched:**

```
Products in these categories Nr 24432 in Kitchen ( Bestsellers ) Nr 11 in Home Improvement > Garden Nr 25 in Hobby > Gärtnerei
```

**Expected Results:**

```
"Kitchen","Home Improvement > Garden", "Hobby > Gärtnerei"
```

This is the regexp that I came up with so far, but it only matches the first occurrance.
Any ideas?

```
Nr [0-9]{1,} in ([0-9A-z >&äÄüÜöÖ]{1,})
```

Comment: What language is this for?  I ask as the various methods of matching everything(instead of just the first match) usually depend on the language.

Comment: I am doing this in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you're currently trying to match them, but this should work:

```
text = "Products in these categories Nr 24432 in Kitchen ( Bestsellers ) Nr 11 in Home Improvement > Garden Nr 25 in Hobby > Gärtnerei "
for m in re.finditer(r"Nr [0-9]{1,} in ([0-9A-z >&äÄüÜöÖ]{1,})", text):
  print m.group(1)
```

[Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#examples).

Also, your second match will match the whole rest of the string.

I suggest changing it to something like:

```
Nr [0-9]+ in (.+?)(?=[^0-9A-z >&äÄüÜöÖ]|$| Nr )
```

`+` means the same as `{1,}`
`.+?` means one or more wild-cards (non-greedily)
`?=` means look-ahead, so it checks if the next character is an invalid character, end-of-line or `" Nr "` - the start of the next match.

Comment: Thanks! This is for Python.